# Can Text-to-speech work on Windows Azure?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, azure

I've got a web app that converts text to audio using Microsoft .NET Speech library (System.Speech).

i want to know if this app can be migrated to Windows Azure, and if Azure can still allow me to use the System.speech namespace without any problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [similar question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/b2d4faa5-e375-4993-b353-b9a0a8c2b2cd), no definite answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you can use [Bing translate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/speak/archive/2010/03/16/bing-translator-with-tts-functionality-now.aspx) to do TTS